# convert cURL to Google App Script

Tags: curl, google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am trying to convert this code to a google app script using the UrlFetchApp and I have no luck and can't find much help online.

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/activities/activities?start_time=2012-01-01T00:00:01.000Z&end_time=2014-10-01T23:59:59.999Z&page_size=10 \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer Access-Token"
```

Any help or direction where to learn how to do this would be much appreciated. Here is the code, I tried:

```
function myFunction() {
var tokenEndpoint = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/activities/activities?start_time=2018-01-01T00:00:01.000Z&end_time=2018-04-01T23:59:59.999Z&page_size=10";

var head = {

  'Authorization':"Bearer " + "<token>",
  'ContentType': 'application/json'
}



var params = {
    headers:  head,


}

var request = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(tokenEndpoint, params); 
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(tokenEndpoint, params); 

var result = response.getContentText();
Logger.log(result);
var resultObject = JSON.parse(result);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us about your tried script?

Comment: Yes! Don't think it's much of a help:

Comment: (i edited my question to include my code)

Comment: Thank you for updating it. Can you try to remove ``'Method':'GET',`` and ``'Accept': 'application/json',``? And then, please modify from ``ContentType`` to ``Content-Type``. If the error occurs, please tell me the error messages.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. I tried it but got an error message in reference to my var response line.  Error:                                                     Request failed for https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/activities/activities?start_time=2018-01-01T00:00:01.000Z&end_time=2018-04-01T23:59:59.999Z&page_size=10 returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Token signature verification failed"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: From the error messages, it seems that the access token you use is wrong. Please confirm it and try again. And can you show us your current script? If you can do, please update your question. It will help users think of your solution.

Comment: Thanks again. It is the right token code. Maybe my format of it is wrong?? Or it is something else?

Comment: Can you show us your current script?

Comment: Yes. I edited my question with my updated code!

Comment: Please modify from ``ContentType`` to ``Content-Type``.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this

```
function sampleGet() {

  var headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer' + access_token,
  };
  var options =
      {
        "method" : "get",
        "headers": headers,
        "contentType": "application/json",
      };
  var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/activities/activities?start_time=2012-01-01T00:00:01.000Z&end_time=2014-10-01T23:59:59.999Z&page_size=10', options).getContentText();
  Logger.log(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now Iget an error that says "invalid_token","error_description":"Access Token not found in cache" But I'm pretty sure, I'm using the token I was assigned. Any thoughts?

Comment: Token get expired. Did you tried using postman/etc for the same? Did request succeed that way ?

Comment: Yeah, I think I have the must current token. Once this is expired, I'll try the new one. I'm not familiar with postman. What is it? Thanks so much for your patience and help!

Comment: Postman is nothing much just a rest client, no issue check your credentials here https://www.hurl.it/

Comment: Hmmm... I got an error there but I'm not sure what to enter.